# What's the feature in Ruby that allows "p *1..10" to print out the numbers 1-10?

Tags: ruby, syntax, splat

```
require 'pp'

p *1..10
```

This prints out 1-10. Why is this so concise? And what else can you do with it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is "the splat" operator. It can be used to explode arrays and ranges and collect values during assignment.

Here the values in an assignment are collected:

```
a, *b = 1,2,3,4

=> a = 1
   b = [2,3,4]
```

In this example the values in the inner array (the `[3,4]` one) is exploded and collected to the containing array:

```
a = [1,2, *[3,4]]

=> a = [1,2,3,4]
```

You can define functions that collect arguments into an array:

```
def foo(*args)
  p args
end

foo(1,2,"three",4)

=> [1,2,"three",4]
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? My answer didn't go into detail on any one aspect on the grounds that I didn't know which bit was confusing the OP, but this is great for the splat operator.

Answer (score 8):

Well:

- `require pp` imports the pretty-printing functionality
- `p` is a pretty-printing method with varargs, which pretty-prints each argument
- `*` means "expand the argument *into* varargs" instead of treating it as a single argument
- 1..10 is [range sequence syntax](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Ranges) in Ruby

Does that explain it adequately? If not, please elaborate on which bit is confusing.